# Laravel 'Class not found'

Tags: php, laravel

excuse me for me english, It's not good.

I'm trying to use a class for upload files, but the console show me

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class
>   'uploadFiles\qqFileUploader' not
>   found","file":"C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\traductor\app\controllers\publico\HomeController.php","line":27}}

I have been searching information about it, but not resolve my problem.

This is the method in the controller:

```
public function setFiles() {
    try {
        $obj= new \uploadFiles\qqFileUploader();

        $files = array("file" => \Request::post("qqfile"));


        $rules = array(
            'file' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,txt',
            'size' => '1024000'
        );


        $validation = \Validator::make($files, $rules);



        if ($validation->fails()) {
            throw new \Exception($validation->errors()->first());
        } else {
            return \Response::make('success', 200);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return \Response::make($e->getMessage(), 400);
    }
}
```

I do the changes on

> star/global.php

and I put this code app_path().'/facades', after, I execute the composer dump-autoload.

Please, help me, thank you.

Comment: Best to remove the commented-out code so it's easier for people to see what's executing.

Answer (score 0):

Myself resolved the problem, I post this because can help to any else. The problem is that laravel associates the name of file with the name of class. This have to be the same

Answer (score 0):

Try to running this command

***composer dump-autoload***